# Infinite recursion in toString(), how can I prevent this?

Tags: java, recursion, tostring

I've searched through StackOverflow trying to figure this out "on my own", with no luck. I think I'm sitting on a problem of infinite recursion in my `toString()`-method, but I'm not certain as I'm quite new to this.

I think providing you with my code, first of all, will make the problem appear clearer to you:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class User{
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<User> friends;
    private static ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    public User(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.friends = new ArrayList<User>();
        users.add(this);
    }

    public void addFriend(User friend){
        friends.add(friend);
    }

    public static void connect(User user1, User user2){
        user1.addFriend(user2);
        user2.addFriend(user1);
    }

    public static ArrayList<User> getUsers(){
        return users;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("%s : %s", name, friends);
    }   
}
```

I'm not sure if you can see what I'm trying to do, but the format of my `toString` is supposed to be like this:

name : {friend1, friend2, friend3, ...}

For example, a user “Alice” with friends “Bob” and “Charlie” would print like this

Alice : {Bob, Charlie, }

I'm not quite sure how I'm supposed to proceed to achieve this. Any help would be much appreciated. I also apologize if this has been answered before, but I didn't understand any of the answers I found earlier.

This is my `main`-method, might also be helpful:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        User bob = new User("Bob");
        User alice = new User("Alice");
        User charlie = new User("Charlie");

        User.connect(alice, bob);
        User.connect(alice, charlie);

        System.out.println(User.getUsers());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are gettting? What is going wrong?

Comment: @CodeGhost The error is so incredibly long I can't fit it all, and that's why I didn't include it in the first place, but I'll post what I can of it here:

Edit: It's too long by over 50k characters.. I don't know what part of the error is most important. Is there a way to post images here, so I can show you?

Comment: @CodeGhost

at User.toString(User.java:28)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
 at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printString(Formatter.java:2886)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2763)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
 at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)



These few lines repeat themselves mostly.

Comment: The line 28 is the following one: public String toString(){
        return String.format("%s : %s", name, friends);
    } . And exception is thrown from Main.java in the following line: System.out.println(User.getUsers());

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal Yes, I thought the error might be on that line, however, I'm struggling with understanding exactly what's wrong and how to do it correctly.

Comment: Ok, I wanted to help others to quickly find out which line causes the problem, because your comment indicated that it is in line 28, but everyone had to spend some time to count which exact is that 28th line. Hope this helped a bit.

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal Oh, OK. I'm sorry you had to go through the trouble of finding it, rather than me doing it in the first place. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over the "friends" List and just print the name of each.  Because you're printing each friend, that includes the friends' friends which is why you're getting infinite recursion.

Try something like

```
public String toString() {
    int count = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{\"name\"=" + name + ", \"friends\"=[");
    for (User friend : friends) {
        sb.append(friend.getName());
        if (++count < friends.size()) sb.append(", ");
    }
    sb.append("]}");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll get right on trying that approach. I'll look into what StringBuilder is first though, as I'm not familiar with it. Feel free to explain if you care to, as it might be more helpful than what I can find googling it.

Comment: It's just a more memory efficient construct for editing strings than string concatenation.  Feel free to just use string concatenation though.

Comment: If you're using Java 8, you could use something like `List<String> friendNames = friends.stream().map(friend -> friend.name).collect(Collectors.toList());` — which is saying 'turn my list of `Friend` into a list of `String name`. See a post [like this one for a more in-depth explanation on working with collections in this way](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-applying-lambdas-to-java-collections/). Either way, worth understanding StringBuilders generally too

Comment: @shmosel yes you're right.  i meant that it doesn't have to constantly reallocate in memory, but time efficiency is the point, you're right.

Comment: @anotherdave I'm indeed using Java 8. Thank you for the input and the link, I'll check it out. Seems like something that would be good to know, and I like the way you explained it - as a rookie I sometimes need ELI5 explanation, and you gave me that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, Mike. I really appreciate it. The way you went about solving the problem worked, and I've yet to see any other ways to go about it, except for @anotherdave's answer, which was also great. I'll accept your answer, as it solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the issue is that when you call `Alice.toString()`, and you start iterating over the list of Alice's friends, it calls each friend's `toString()`.

If `Alice` is friends with `Bob`, and `Bob` is ALSO friends with `Alice`, then you end up bouncing back and forth between `Alice.toString()` and `Bob.toString()` indefinitely.

Comment: That makes total sense.. Didn't even occur to me. Do you have any way of guiding me on the right path to make this work, and prevent this bouncing back and forth from happening? I'll of course try to fix it myself, but a push on the right path would be much appreciated.

Comment: See Mike's answer.

Answer (score 1):

From my pont of view, the problem could be that once you call to the toString, trying to display all the users, what happends is that in the toString method you call to the toString of the friends os the user, successively.

In order to avoid recursivity, try to iterate over the list of friends of the user and concat an empty string with the information of the friends of the user, not declaring again the friends of the friends. To sum up, avoid recursivity :)